# SQLite3 read and write are extremely slow for large table of > 28 G

Tags: database, sqlite

SQL read and write performace are extremely slow when the table size grow larger

Here is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE stock_price_minute_data (
                    "ticker" TEXT NOT NULL,
                    "timestamp" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                    "open" FLOAT NOT NULL, 
                    "high" FLOAT, 
                    "low" FLOAT, 
                    "close" FLOAT, 
                    "volume" FLOAT,
                    "vwap" FLOAT,
                    PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp" , "ticker")
                    );
```

I have ~280 Million records (table size 28G).

Query like below took more than 5 mins to get me an answer

```
select count(*) from stock_price_minute_data where ticker = 'SNPS';
```

if i create per ticker table , each table is < 100 MB and have ~500K records. In this case the performance is good (sub seconds)

```
CREATE TABLE stock_price_minute_data_SNPS (
                    "ticker" TEXT NOT NULL,
                    "timestamp" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                    "open" FLOAT NOT NULL, 
                    "high" FLOAT, 
                    "low" FLOAT, 
                    "close" FLOAT, 
                    "volume" FLOAT,
                    "vwap" FLOAT,
                    PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp" , "ticker")
                    );
select count(*) from stock_price_minute_data_SNPS where ticker = 'SNPS';
```

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN  select count(*) from stock_price_minute_data where ticker = 'SNPS';
```

Outputs

```
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE stock_price_minute_data USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_stock_price_minute_data_1
```

Is this because as the table size grow the index grow and it does not fit on memory? how to debug the exact cause?

Comment: An index on `ticker` maybe...

Comment: isn't primary key is auto indexed? ticker is already part of primary key

Comment: `ticker` is not the PRIMARY KEY. It is part of the primary key but it is the 2nd column defined in it. Usually the 1st column in the definition of a composite index benefits of the index in a query like the one you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is in case of composite primary key (as in my case above) SQLite will create an index but the query should have timestamp as a first variable in query clause. In my case i have ticker so it is resorting to a full table scan

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN  select count(*) from stock_price_minute_data where ticker = 'SNPS';
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE stock_price_minute_data USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_stock_price_minute_data_1
```

```
sqlite> PRAGMA index_info('sqlite_autoindex_stock_price_minute_data_1');
seqno|cid|name
0|1|timestamp
1|0|ticker
sqlite> PRAGMA index_list('stock_price_minute_data');
seq|name|unique|origin|partial
0|sqlite_autoindex_stock_price_minute_data_1|1|pk|0
```